# Text formatting relative to environment (theorems)

Tags: environments, thmtools

I've gotten the code below from another post and, I'm not sure whether or not this is possible but, I would like to define an alternate `\myemph` command whose effect would depend on the theorem environment in which it is embedded.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{amsthm,eso-pic,thmtools,framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \definecolor{localblue}{RGB}{55, 115, 180}
    \definecolor{localgreen}{RGB}{80, 140, 30}

\newcommand{\myemph}[1]{\emph{\textcolor{localblue}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\miemph}[1]{\emph{\textcolor{localgreen}{#1}}}


    \colorlet{headcolordefn}{localblue}
    \colorlet{rulecolordefn}{localblue}
    \newenvironment{leftbardefn}{%
        \def\FrameCommand{{\color{rulecolordefn}\vrule width 3pt} \hspace{10pt}}%
        \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
        {\endMakeFramed}
        \declaretheoremstyle[
          headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,%
          notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,%
          notebraces={}{},%
          headpunct=,%
          bodyfont=,%
          headformat=\color{headcolordefn}\NAME~\NUMBER\hfill\NOTE\smallskip\linebreak,%
          preheadhook=\begin{leftbardefn},
          postfoothook=\end{leftbardefn},%
                           ]{customDefinition}
\declaretheorem[
               title=Definition,style=customDefinition, numberwithin=section
               ]{defn}



    \colorlet{headcolorthm}{localgreen}
    \colorlet{rulecolorthm}{localgreen}
    \newenvironment{leftbarthm}{%
        \def\FrameCommand{{\color{rulecolorthm}\vrule width 3pt} \hspace{10pt}}%
        \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
        {\endMakeFramed}
        \declaretheoremstyle[
        headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,%
        notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,%
        notebraces={}{},%
        headpunct=,%
        bodyfont=,%
        headformat=\color{headcolorthm}\NAME~\NUMBER\hfill\NOTE\smallskip\linebreak,%
        preheadhook=\begin{leftbarthm},
        postfoothook=\end{leftbarthm},%
                         ]{customTheorem}
\declaretheorem[
               title=Theorem,style=customTheorem, numberwithin=section, sibling=defn
               ]{thrm}

 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

            \begin{defn}[object]
                Such-and-such is said to be an \myemph{object} when so-and-so is verified.
            \end{defn}
\lipsum[2]
            \begin{thrm}[of the day]
                If such-and-such \miemph{conditions} are met, then we're happy.
            \end{thrm}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I've got a series of different 'theorem' styles with specific colors, and I would for my command to color the text relative to the one defined in the style, e.g. I'd like it to render

[image]

with the previous code. Is there anyway to accomplish this without too many headaches?

EDIT:
as required in the comments, I modified the example to provide a more detailed one. It renders:

[image]

So my question really is: is there a way to merge the \myemph and \miemph commands into one (there are of course more environments than those two: propositions, corollaries...)?

Comment: Not very clear to me. Should the theorem note (‘object’) be placed in the right margin?

Comment: No, that is not what I want to modify (in part because some theorems have names, and in French this might render "Théorème 1.4:      de la valeur intermédiaire" for instance, which was what I meant to do - and I'd like to keep the consistency arcoss the various styles); I was refering to the 'object' in italics in the body of the text rather - the word that I would like to be emphasized within the text itself. Plus I  mean to have the entirety of the entry to the right of the sidebar.

Comment: You may stick to a fixed color name in `\myemph`, but let that color to different theme colors in theorem styles, by using `\colorlet` from `xcolor` package. An example containing two or more such theorem styles would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates what I suggest in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600866/text-formatting-relative-to-environment-theorems#comment1507181_600866):

- All theorem-like environments shares a single theorem style, called `thm@custom`.
- This theorem style makes use of an environment `thm@leftbar`.
- In the `thm@custom` style and `thm@leftbar` environment, a theme color `thm@theme` is used, instead of specific colors like `localblue` and `localgreen`.
- At the begin of each kind of theorem-like environments, the color `thm@theme` is let to the corresponding specific color. This is done by `\AtBeginEnvironment`.

Moreover, `\DeclareEmphSequence` is used to configure the style of `\emph`, so you can directly use `\emph` in theorem-like envs and get the text in desired theme color.

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{amsthm,eso-pic,thmtools,framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \definecolor{localblue}{RGB}{55, 115, 180}
    \definecolor{localgreen}{RGB}{80, 140, 30}

    \newenvironment{thm@leftbar}{%
        \def\FrameCommand{{\color{thm@theme}\vrule width 3pt} \hspace{10pt}}%
        \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
        {\endMakeFramed}
    \declaretheoremstyle[
          headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,%
          notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,%
          notebraces={}{},%
          headpunct=,%
          bodyfont=,%
          headformat=\color{thm@theme}\NAME~\NUMBER\hfill\NOTE\smallskip\linebreak,%
          preheadhook=\begin{thm@leftbar},
          postfoothook=\end{thm@leftbar},%
                           ]{thm@custom}
\declaretheorem[
               title=Definition,style=thm@custom, numberwithin=section
               ]{defn}
\declaretheorem[
               title=Theorem,style=thm@custom, numberwithin=section, sibling=defn
               ]{thrm}

% since latex2e 2020-10-01
% for older latex2e, load etoolbox package
\AtBeginEnvironment{defn}{\colorlet{thm@theme}{localblue}\thmemph}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thrm}{\colorlet{thm@theme}{localgreen}\thmemph}

% since latex2e 2020-02-02
\newcommand\thmemph{%
  \DeclareEmphSequence{\itshape\color{thm@theme}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

            \begin{defn}[object]
                Such-and-such is said to be an \emph{object} when so-and-so is verified.
            \end{defn}
\lipsum[2]
            \begin{thrm}[of the day]
                If such-and-such \emph{conditions} are met, then we're happy.
            \end{thrm}
\lipsum[2]

test \verb|\emph| \emph{outside thm-like envs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, okay your question flew right above my head. But even if didn't, I would have been nowhere near producing anything like this.Thanks, that works very nicely!